# Azure DevOps static web app automatically upgraded its node and npm versions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, azure-pipelines

> Recently while deploying a reactjs app as azure static web app, the
> automatic upgradation of node and npm caused error related to peer
> dependency.

Previous versions-

****Using Node version:v14.19.1****

****Using Npm version:6.14.16****

> Current versions-

****Using Node version:v16.18.0****

****Using Npm version:8.19.2****

> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
>
> npm WARN While resolving: @date-io/date-fns@1.1.0
>
> npm WARN Found: date-fns@2.29.3
>
> npm WARN node_modules/date-fns
>
> npm WARN   date-fns@"^2.29.3" from the root project
>
> npm WARN   2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, @date-io/date-fns)
>
> npm WARN
>
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
>
> npm WARN peer date-fns@"2.0.0-alpha.27" from @date-io/date-fns@1.1.0
>
> npm WARN node_modules/@date-io/date-fns
>
> npm WARN   @date-io/date-fns@"1.1.0" from material-table@1.69.3
>
> npm WARN   node_modules/material-table
>
> What is the proper solution to resolve this issue, as I tried adding a
> task in yml file to upgrade node version, it did not work

Comment: Can u share your pipeline code? As you said "Azure DevOps" in your title, I guess you are using a pipeline. If not, Static Web App is an "Azure" product, not part of "Azure DevOps"

Comment: In .yml file its task: azurestaticwebapp@0 ,  so it runs its own node, npm versions provided .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js is determined by project itself. It is not able to be set in YAML Pipeline via adding task.

Refer to this doc: [Configure Azure Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#platform)

You can add a file name:  staticwebapp.config.json to your project and add the following code:

```
{
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:14"
  }
}
```

For example:

[image]

Or you can define the Engines field in Package.json file.

For example:

```
{
 ...
  "engines": {
      "npm": "^6.14.17",
      "node": "^v14.20.1"
  },
....
}
```

**Result:**

[image]